# DJANGO ecommerce website help needed. Different orders have same OrderItems

Tags: python, django

So I am following this tutorial on YouTube to make an eCommerce website using DJANGO but the problem is that now that I'm done with the tutorial I realize something is wrong. So whenever i make a new order, that order has the order items in it, as Order model has a manytomanyfield with OrderItem. So I make one order and save it. But if i make a second order and then save it, the first order's order items will become equal to the second order which shouldn't happen. I've been at this for 4 hours now and I don't know what to do so I'd appreciate your help. Both Orders have different ref_codes so at least that is working properly. Screenshot of admin view of both orders are attached.
Youtube tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YZvRrldjf1Y&t=12766s

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import reverse

# Create your models here.

CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
    ('S', 'Shirt'),
    ('SW', 'Sport Wear'),
    ('OW', 'Outwear'),

)

LABEL_CHOICES = (
    ('P', 'primary'),
    ('S', 'secondary'),
    ('D', 'danger'),

)


class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.FloatField()
    discount_price = models.FloatField(default=0)
    category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=2)
    label = models.CharField(choices=LABEL_CHOICES, max_length=1)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("core:product", kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })

    def get_add_to_cart_url(self):
        return reverse("core:add-to-cart", kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })

    def get_remove_from_cart_url(self):
        return reverse("core:remove-from-cart", kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def get_total_item_price(self):
        return self.quantity * self.item.price

    def get_total_discounted_item_price(self):
        return self.quantity * self.item.discount_price

    def get_amount_saved(self):
        return self.get_total_item_price() - self.get_total_discounted_item_price()

    def get_final_price(self):
        if self.item.discount_price:
            return self.get_total_discounted_item_price()
        return self.get_total_item_price()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.quantity} of {self.item.title}"


class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ref_code = models.CharField(max_length=20,default="0")
    items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ordered_date = models.DateTimeField()
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    billing_address = models.ForeignKey('BillingAddress', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    being_delivered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    received = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    refund_requested = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    refund_granted = models.BooleanField(default=False)





    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def get_total(self):
        total = 0
        for order_item in self.items.all():
            total += order_item.get_final_price()
        return total
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, View
from django.contrib import messages
from .models import *
from django.utils import timezone
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from .forms import *
import random
import string


# Create your views here.

def create_ref_code():
    return ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits, k=20))


class CheckoutView(View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form = CheckoutForm()
        order = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user, ordered=False)
        stuff_for_frontend = {
            'form': form,
            'order': order,
        }
        return render(self.request, 'checkout.html', stuff_for_frontend)

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form = CheckoutForm(self.request.POST or None)
        try:
            order = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user, ordered=False)
            if form.is_valid():

                if not ('0' <= form.cleaned_data.get('mobile_number') <= '99999999999'):
                    messages.warning(self.request, "Mobile Number is invalid")

                    messages.warning(self.request, "Failed Checkout")
                    return redirect('core:checkout')

                street_address = form.cleaned_data.get('street_address')
                apartment_address = form.cleaned_data.get('apartment_address')
                mobile_number = form.cleaned_data.get('mobile_number')
                city = form.cleaned_data.get('city')
                zip = form.cleaned_data.get('zip')
                # same_shipping_address = form.cleaned_data.get('same_shipping_address')
                # save_info = form.cleaned_data.get('save_info')
                payment_option = form.cleaned_data.get('payment_option')
                billing_address = BillingAddress(
                    user=self.request.user,
                    street_address=street_address,
                    apartment_address=apartment_address,
                    mobile_number=mobile_number,
                    city=city,
                    zip=zip

                )
                billing_address.save()
                order.billing_address = billing_address
                order.ordered = True
                order.ref_code = create_ref_code()
                order.save()

                messages.success(self.request, "Your order was successful")
                return redirect('/')
            messages.warning(self.request, "Failed Checkout")
            return redirect('core:checkout')
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            messages.error(self.request, "You do not have an active order")
            return redirect("core:order-summary")


class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Item
    paginate_by = 10
    template_name = "home.html"


class ItemDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Item
    template_name = 'product.html'


class OrderSummary(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            order = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user, ordered=False)
            stuff_for_frontend = {
                'object': order
            }
            return render(self.request, 'order_summary.html', stuff_for_frontend)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            messages.error(self.request, "You do not have an active order")
            return redirect("/")


@login_required
def add_to_cart(request, slug):
    item = get_object_or_404(Item, slug=slug)
    order_item, created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(item=item, user=request.user, ordered=False)
    order_qs = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user, ordered=False)
    if order_qs.exists():
        order = order_qs[0]
        print(order_qs)
        if order.items.filter(item__slug=item.slug).exists():
            order_item.quantity += 1
            order_item.save()
            messages.info(request, "This item's quantity was updated")
            return redirect("core:order-summary")
        else:
            order.items.add(order_item)
            messages.info(request, "This item was added to your cart")
            return redirect("core:order-summary")

    else:

        order = Order.objects.create(user=request.user, ordered_date=timezone.now())
        order.items.add(order_item)
        messages.info(request, "This item was added to your cart")
        return redirect("core:order-summary")


@login_required
def remove_from_cart(request, slug):
    item = get_object_or_404(Item, slug=slug)
    order_qs = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user, ordered=False)
    if order_qs.exists():
        order = order_qs[0]

        if order.items.filter(item__slug=item.slug).exists():
            order_item = OrderItem.objects.filter(item=item, user=request.user, ordered=False)[0]

            order.items.remove(order_item)
            messages.info(request, "This item was removed from your cart")
            return redirect("core:order-summary")
        else:
            messages.info(request, "This item was not in your cart")
            return redirect("core:product", slug=slug)
    else:
        messages.info(request, "You do not have an active order")
        return redirect("core:product", slug=slug)


@login_required
def remove_single_item_from_cart(request, slug):
    item = get_object_or_404(Item, slug=slug)
    order_qs = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user, ordered=False)
    if order_qs.exists():
        order = order_qs[0]

        if order.items.filter(item__slug=item.slug).exists():
            order_item = OrderItem.objects.filter(item=item, user=request.user, ordered=False)[0]
            if order_item.quantity > 1:
                order_item.quantity -= 1
                messages.info(request, "This item quantity was updated")
            else:
                order.items.remove(order_item)
                messages.info(request, "This item was removed from your cart")
            order_item.save()

            return redirect("core:order-summary")
        else:
            messages.info(request, "This item was not in your cart")
            return redirect("core:product", slug=slug)
    else:
        messages.info(request, "You do not have an active order")
        return redirect("core:product", slug=slug)
```

order-summary.html (loaded when the user wants to see their cart)

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

  {%block content%}


  <!--Main layout-->
  <main>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="table-responsive text-nowrap">
          <h2>Order Summary</h2>
          <table class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">Item title</th>
                <th scope="col">Price</th>
                <th scope="col">Discounted Price</th>
                <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
                <th scope="col">Total Item Price</th>

              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                {%for order_item in object.items.all%}
                  <th scope="row">{{forloop.counter}}</th>
                  <td>{{order_item.item.title}}</td>
                  <td>{{order_item.item.price}}</td>
                  <td>{{order_item.item.discount_price}}</td>
                  <td><a href="{% url 'core:remove-single-item-from-cart' order_item.item.slug  %}"><i class="fas fa-minus mr-2"></i></a>{{order_item.quantity}}<a href="{% url 'core:add-to-cart' order_item.item.slug  %}"><i class="fas fa-plus ml-2"></i></a></td>
                  <td>
                    {%if order_item.item.discount_price%}

                      ${{order_item.get_total_discounted_item_price}}
                      <span class="badge badge-success">Saving ${{order_item.get_amount_saved}}</span>

                    {%else%}

                      ${{order_item.get_total_item_price}}

                    {%endif%}
                    <a style="color:red;"  href="{% url 'core:remove-from-cart' order_item.item.slug  %}"><i class="fas fa-trash float-right"></i></a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                {%empty%}
                <tr>
                  <td colspan='5'>Your cart is empty</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="6">
                    <a class="btn btn-dark float-right " href="/">Continue Shopping</a>
                  </td>
                </tr>


              {%endfor%}
              {%if object.get_total %}
              <tr>
                <td colspan="5"><b>Order Total</b></td>
                <td colspan="5"><b>${{object.get_total}}</b></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="6">
                  <a class="btn btn-primary float-right ml-2" href="/checkout">Proceed to checkout</a>
                  <a class="btn btn-dark float-right " href="/">Continue Shopping</a>
                </td>
              </tr>
            {%endif%}
            </tbody>
          </table>

        </div>



    </div>
  </main>
  <!--Main layout-->

  {%endblock content%}
```

First Order:
[image: First Order]

Second Order:
[image: Second order]

Answer (score 0):

OrderItems should have a ForeignKey to Order; Orders shouldn't have a ManyToManyField to OrderItems since one OrderItem shouldn't be able to belong to multiple orders.

Also, OrderItems should cache the price of the item ordered - otherwise you couldn't e.g. run reports on prices of items sold over time, if you were to change the item's price afterwards.

Comment: Thankyou. How would i go about caching the prices. Do i just create a field "price = self.item.price"?

Comment: Yes. I'd recommend `unit_price`, `quantity`, `discount`, `total_price`, where `total_price = (unit_price * quantity) - discount`, but the semantics are up to you to decide.